# What I need to Compile and Debug OpenCover solution?

Tags: opencover

I'm using OpenCover (https://github.com/OpenCover/opencover) for code coverage and it has a bug of AccessViolationException. I already opened an issue for the problem but I want to solve it by myself. The problem is that I even cannot compile it in Visual Studio 2017. I've already followed the instructions in the documentation but without success. Could anyone help me?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm sorry that currently I don't have the time and resources to try this myself.
I'll try to see if someone in my company is interested and can find the time. Perhaps you should contact the guy that did debug it back (in the GitHub thread) then and ask his help.
I did contact Shaun Wilde (via LinkedIn) a few months ago to ask about the project's support in general, and his answer was that he is no longer interested in the project.
Still, perhaps as more people ask, perhaps he'll be willing to check this problem or at least to explain better how to compile and debug it. Worth a try. In long run

Comment: @ZvikaBerkovich - I didn't say I wasn't interested just one that "I needed to put to one side for a while." - it is a lot of effort to maintain an open source project and sometimes real-life just gets in the way.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you should consider approaching that project's main developer directly.
I would love to know of any progress as we're getting this too.

Note: we did find the following temp workaround: reducing the number of covered classes via filter parameters of OpenCover.Console.exe makes this go away. (we filtered the classes we didn't actually need coverage on reducing from 10K classes to 8.5K)

Comment: Hi @zvika-berkovich, thank you for the answer. I already limited the number of classes but it's still too large. I'm trying to debug it using WinDbg, it seems that it's not possible with Visual Studio since OpenCover.Profiler.dll implement and is called from CLR API. I also found this thread https://github.com/OpenCover/opencover/issues/329 where this guy debug it but I've followed the same procedures but without success. Unfortunately, the Exception occurs randomly which turns out to be more difficult to simulate.